# How to use transform.forward that only acknowledges one axis of rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a rolling ball game, and the way I want it to work is based on constant forward movement and rotation based turning.
I'm using force, which then has the ball roll forward.
My Issue here is that I would like the ball to move forward based on where it's "facing". Using Vector3.forward only moves it according to world space and transform.forward will start going backwards because the ball rolls over, upside down.
How can I make it so transform.forward ignores my forward turning, only being effected by the sideways turning?

Answer (score 3):

"forward" is hard to imagine on a sphere.

You add speed when rotating around the X-axis (ball moves "forward")
For direction control, you rotate around global Y-axis.
The transform.forward will spin around the object. But the `transform.right` (local x-axis so to say) stays stable.
So we only need the [Vector3.Cross](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) Product of the `transform.right` and the global `Vector3.Up`.

```
Vector3 forward = Vector3.Cross(transform.right, Vector3.up);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector math for this. Take the cross product between the local right and the world up:

```
private static Vector3 GetRollingForward(Vector3 localRight)
{
    return Vector3.Cross(localRight, Vector3.up);
}

// ...

void Update()
{
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position 
            + GetRollingForward(transform.right));
}
```